# Space Between Pixels

Tags: java, pixel

I'm relatively new to programming and have a question about drawing to the display.  I'm sure this is not specific to Java, but I am learning Java so I will ask it in that context.  Here is some context for the question:

From the Wikipedia entry for "Pixel" (emphasis added):
"In digital imaging, a pixel ... is the **smallest controllable element of a picture** represented on the screen."

From the Java API entry for Class "Graphics" (emphasis added): 
"Operations that draw the outline of a figure operate by traversing an **infinitely thin path between pixels** with a pixel-sized pen that hangs down and to the right of the anchor point on the path."

My question is:

How is Java able to represent outlines of figures as the space between pixels when a pixel is the smallest controllable element of a display?

Put another way:

0|0

The "0"s above are two pixels.  The "|" above is the "infinitely thin path between pixels."  If only the "0"s can change, how does Java make the "|" visible to humans?  Does it change the color of the edges of the "0"s?  (Is that what "pixel-sized pen" means - it colors half of both pixels?)

Comment: This has more to do with the underlying graphics engine then Java.  There are many factors which will effect the size of line between two points and any number of algorithms that might be used, you also have to consider if antialiasing is enabled or not as this can introduce "particular" filled pixels (translucent).  On a whole, the question is quite broad and relates more to general graphics then Java

Comment: Thanks, but this question isn't about the size of a line between two points.  It's a question about how it is possible for a line to appear on the screen in the first place when it centers on space "between" the only medium (pixels) for showing images on the screen.

Comment: As a pixel is "_the smallest controllable element of a picture_" coloring the edges or a half of a pixel is impossible as then those would be the smallest "controllable element".  A pixel must take on a single specific value, usually made up of three 8-bit values -- one each for red, green, and blue.  As @MadProgrammer mentioned, antialiasing and font-smoothing may alter the actual on-screen values from what the program sent but in the end that physical pixel has exactly one state.

Comment: That "infinitely thin" line is simply used to break the tie when the algorithm needs to choose which pixel to color.  It's an imaginary line.

Comment: So, the "pixel sized pen" that traverses the "infinitely thin, imaginary" line actually gets "tie broken" to one pixel or the other?  Otherwise, if it is a "pixel size pen" and travels a line between pixels, it would color at least some of both pixels (which is not possible).

Comment: A "pixel sized pen" generally means that it's only going to touch one pixel at a time as it traverses the path, not two, otherwise it wouldn't need to break a tie.

Comment: OK.  I think I get it - I was misreading the API.  The pixel-size pen hangs down and to the right of that imaginary line - it does not traverse the line.  That was my misunderstanding.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> that **hangs down and to the right** of the anchor point on the path

The pen will draw the right `0`.

Comment: @WilliamPrice: Oops; fixed.